# laravel отправить на почту логин пароль после сброса

Tags: php, laravel, laravel5

Использую стандартный сброс пароля от Laravel. Все работает все настроил. Но осталась задача отправить пароль новый пользователю. Ни пойму как, скорее всего где перехватывать и отправлять на почту пароль?.

PS

> при регистрации же отправляется пароль и логин на почту. хотелось бы когда пользователь перешел по токену и заполнил форму сброса пароля, ему пришел новый пароль на почту.

Comment: Не думаю что Laravel такое позволяет в целях безопасности. У них это устроено так чтобы на почту слалась ссылка с токеном, перейдя по которой устанавливается новый пароль на сайте.

Comment: при регистрации же отправляется пароль и логин на почту. хотелось бы когда пользователь перешел по токену и заполнил форму сброса пароля, ему пришел новый пароль на почту.

Comment: Для этого вам придется сделать переназначение функции public function reset(Request $request) trait`а ResetsPasswords в своем контроллере и там у вас будет доступ к новому паролю. Функция resetPassword к сожалению protected.

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо всем большое вот разобрался

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{
  use ResetsPasswords {
    // переопределяем метод trait
    reset as private reset_foo;
  }
  *****
  ****
  *****
  // мой обработчик
  function reset(Request $request)
  {
    // вызываем стандартный обработчик 
    $resp = $this->reset_foo($request);

    $email = $request->get('email');
    $password = $request->get('password');

    // сдесь делаю что надо

    return $resp;
  }
```